# Need specifications to operate this stepper motor with RPi or Arduino

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, stepper-motor

Here is the [disassembled stepper motor that I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fURCf.jpg):

Contains the photo of the motor, and the label that's on the bottom of the motor.

[image: disassembled stepper motor]
[image: disassembled stepper motor]

I need to identify this stepper motor that was retrieved from scrap for a project. Budget constraints force us to use the scrap motor. I tried to drive this using a L298 H Bridge, but I couldn't find the right bit sequences to get this running smoothly. I also tried to search for a specifications sheet in the internet with the label, unsuccessfully.

I'm using either an RPi or Arduino board to run this.

I just need a pin diagram and the specifications of the motor, if you guys have seen this type before.

Answer (score 1):

The [Marlin P. Jones Co. page for this item](http://www.mpja.com/Stepper-Motor-NEMA-23-384V/productinfo/17607%20MS/) has a link to a pdf data sheet with the following diagram and stepping sequence.

[image: pin diagram & step chart]

The pdf file shows the following specifications:

> 17607-MS
>   1.8 DEG. 3.84V NEMA 23 STEPMOTOR
>   SHINANO KENSHI
>   P/N: STP-57D211
>   3.84VDC/4.7ohms/0.8A 2 Phase Uni-Polar 5 lead Step Motor with 6.5mm dia. X 18mm steel shaft with a 3/4 dia., 16 tooth, plastic cog belt gear attached by a steel roll pin. Ball bearings, 3" leads, 4 corner mounting holes, Removable anti vibration rubber/steel mtg. bracket.
>   L: 2"(Body) SQ: 2-3/16"               WT: 1.5